# where is clang executables after building LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

after git clone llvm-project from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.

I generated build credentials using Cmake commandline like this:

```
cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 \
-DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=X86 \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
-DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=1 \
-DCLANG_BUILD_EXAMPLES=1 \
-G "Unix Makefiles" \
../llvm/
```

after makefile was generated, I then use make to build the project `make -j8`. somehow after build completion, `clang` and `clang++` etc. are nowhere to be found in `/build/bin/`.

To my knowledge, if I didn't specify LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTs, it will build LLVM and clang both by default. why are `clang` executables missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECT` and put the source code folder of clang in the same level of llvm source folder. The folder name must match the value of `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECT`